# Question about the tense of "is" in "We are sorry that we thought it is well-known"

Tags: grammar, tense

> Yes, Smith's paper is a classic. We are sorry that we thought it **is** well-known and did not cite it.

I do not feel secure with the tense here. After the verb 'thought', is 'is' okay? Or should it be 'was'?

Comment: This makes little sense, and there must be more context. In the first place, is the speaker apologizing for thinking that the paper was well known, or for failing to cite it? Also, why would someone fail to cite a paper merely because it is well known—or unknown, for that matter?

Comment: I did not cite it simply because none will cite newton's paper anymore.

Comment: Ah! The first lesson of academe: cite, cite, and cite again. Also, in English we capitalize proper names such as _Sir Isaac Newton,_  and _none_ is not the same as _no one_ or _no-one._ Is the speaker apologizing for thinking that the paper was well known, for failing to cite it, or for the entire event?

Comment: As you have phrased the sentence, it sounds as if you are apologizing for thinking that Newton's paper is well known. Is that your intention? This has nothing to do with the tense of **to be.**

Comment: It is a paper in 1955.

Comment: How nice to know! But see previous comment.

Comment: It is far, far, more common to say "I thought it was" than "I thought it is". (I am not sure if "I thought it is" is wrong, though.)

Comment: You just don't understand the question in my comment at all, do you?

Comment: What a strange sentence! Still, you asked about the grammar. Since the status of the paper as well-known is still current at the time of the utterance, it is possible to use the present tense. It can, optionally, be backshifted to past tense; it's a free choice really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, Smith's paper is a classic. We are sorry that we thought it is
>   well-known and did not cite it.

You can use either verb. *is* or *was*

It depends on what you want to express in the sentence.

You have a Complex Sentence with one main (independent) clause and TWO dependent clauses:

Main: We are sorry and did not cite it.

Dependent **one**: that we thought [a noun dependent clause]

Dependent **two**: (that) it is well-known [a noun dependent clause]

The verb that you use in clause **two** relies on clause **one**:

“…that we thought” | “(that) it is/was well-known”

I’ll bold the reasons…

*thought* is past tense, and if you want **to show another completed action** in the past, use the past tense ***was*** [I *needed* to see a doctor because I *felt* sick.]

Again,

*thought* is past tense, and if you want **to state a general truth**, use the present tense ***is*** [Nicolaus Copernicus *believed* the Sun *is* the center of our solar system, not the Earth.]

This is based on this chart, of which I used your first dependent clause to fill in for the independent clause in the first column “Sequence of Tense in Independent Clause”

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sequence.htm

CORRECT: We are sorry that we thought it is well-known and did not cite it.

CORRECT: We are sorry that we thought it was well-known and did not cite it

Proof that the second dependent clause is relying on the first and can substitute for "Tense In Independent Clause" in the chart:

*We are sorry that we thought it is/was well-known and did not cite it.*

The main clause uses the noun dependent clause “that we thought” as a predicate nominative (a noun) after the linking verb “are” to explain “We”; the verb “thought” is transitive in the noun clause and therefore, takes an object, a direct object, which is the second noun clause with the understood relative pronoun (that) introducing the clause “(that) it is/was well-known.”

Present Tense:

http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html